# Deduct template parameter fail while using if constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, function-templates

I am trying to figure out how the sfinae concept works in C++. But I can't convince the object-type compiler if `bool` is `true` or `false`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "a\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    void ioo() { std::cout << "b\n"; }
};

template<class T>
void f(const T& ob, bool value = false)
{
    if constexpr (!value) ob.foo();
    else  ob.ioo();
}

int main()
{
    A ob1;
    B ob2;
    f(ob1, true);
    f(ob2, false);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to let the `bool` parameter to be part of template. In your case, bool `value` is a run  time parameter.

By adding the `value` as non-template parameter, [your code can compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rn7E19EKT):

```
template<bool Flag, class T>
//       ^^^^^^^^
void f(const T& ob)
{
    if constexpr (Flag) {
        ob.foo();
    }
    else
        ob.ioo();
}
```

and you may call like:

```
f<true>(ob1);
f<false>(ob2);
```

As a side note, your `A::foo()` and `B::ioo()` must be `const` qualified member functions, as you want to call, with a `const` objects of each classes inside the `f`.

---

That being said, the `bool` parameter is redundant if you can use the [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same

template<class T>
void f(const T& ob)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
        ob.foo();
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, B>)
        ob.ioo();
}
```

Now call needs to be just:

```
f(ob1);
f(ob2);
```